# Intranet Extranet authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, intranet, extranet

I have developed a php/mysql application which need to be accessed via both intranet and extranet. I want to give access to a certain page(add_company_details.php) to both intranet and extranet. How can I do that?

Basically I want to give the access to extranet only for some parts of the application. I have poor network knowledge. Do I need to give some ssl certificate or user/password authentication? Please help me. Thanks in advance. We use linux server with apache/php/mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the IP address of the client computer and enable or disable pages based on that.

Look at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. If it's an address on your Intranet, enable or disable the page as appropriate. Similarly, you can enable or disable pages for Extranet visitors.

You will still need to authenticate your visitors. There's no specific need for an SSL certificate, but it's the only reliable way to guarantee the security of password exchanges.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think I now got some idea. Sorry I can not give votes because of I only have 1 reputation:).